# Jenkins - Configuring JDK - Only Textbox, and auto-install fails

Tags: java, android, jenkins

I'm trying to create a Jenkins based build-server for our Android App. 
I'm using a CentOS machine (Virtual) with the latest Jenkins (1.638), and I am unable to get the build to complete successfully.

The build is failing because it's unable to auto-install a JDK (On the machine, there's OpenJDK 24.91-b01 a-la 1.7.0_91)

```
java.io.IOException: JDK data is empty.
    at hudson.tools.JDKInstaller.locate(JDKInstaller.java:418)
    at hudson.tools.JDKInstaller.performInstallation(JDKInstaller.java:134)
    at hudson.tools.InstallerTranslator.getToolHome(InstallerTranslator.java:68)
    at hudson.tools.ToolLocationNodeProperty.getToolHome(ToolLocationNodeProperty.java:108)
    at hudson.tools.ToolInstallation.translateFor(ToolInstallation.java:206)
    at hudson.model.JDK.forNode(JDK.java:143)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.getEnvironment(AbstractProject.java:358)
    at hudson.model.Run.getEnvironment(Run.java:2232)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getEnvironment(AbstractBuild.java:941)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1036)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:485)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1275)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:610)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:532)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Finished: FAILURE
```

On the `Manage Jenkins` screen, I don't get a selection box for JDK (and other auto-installers: ANT, Maven, Gradle, ...)

[image: JDK Definitions section]

SO:

1. Why don't I get a selection box? What values should I put in that would work? How to fix that?
2. I'm worried that installing a JDK manually on my own would install it globally, thus causing a JDK versions conflict for Jenkins (see [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Red+Hat+distributions#InstallingJenkinsonRedHatdistributions-ImportantNoteonCentOSJava) about the CentOS installation). Should this something I need to take under consideration?

Comment: @StackFlowed - I wanted an autoinstall.. I don't want to have to login to the server for JDK upgrades...
Can't I have a proper auto-install?

Comment: Attached image is from the admin console ("Manage Jenkins")...

Comment: Last suggestion might sound stupid but have you tried putting a version? like 8u66 or the link to download that version ?

Comment: Yeah, I get the same error. 
(It's not stupid, it was the 1st thing that I tried, and I tried it multiple times with different values. Still a bust).

Comment: Any idea of this is being tracked in a Jenkins JIRA? Not providing an auto-complete option here seems ridiculous.

Comment: I have the same issue. It's not related to JDK only, in fact I see exactly the same behavior when I try to install a different version of Maven from Apache: I should see a list of available versions but I have an empty text field instead. In my case I'm running Jenkins v1.609.1 on RedHat Openshift PaaS.

Answer (score 0):

The only source I found which documentes the JDK ID is the jenkins source code of [JDKInstaller.java](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/35df984e25c3422ded2d129cca4801166d616c15/core/src/main/java/hudson/tools/JDKInstaller.java):

> The release ID that Sun assigns to each JDK, such as
>   "jdk-6u13-oth-JPR@CDS-CDS_Developer"
>
> This ID can be seen in the "ProductRef" query parameter of the download page, like
>   https://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_Developer-Site/en_US/-/USD/ViewProductDetail-Start?ProductRef=jdk-6u13-oth-JPR@CDS-CDS_Developer

But it seems, that this page does not exist. I fixed the problem by installing a different JDK to run Jenkins. JDK 8u66 didn't work, but JDK 8u60 worked like a charm. After installing the older JDK I had to update the available updates from the plugin site. Afterwards I got the classic drop down box, where I could choose the Java version from.